# Use rpad in delphi grid

Tags: delphi, vcl, tdbgrid

Use rpad in tdbgrid not working correctly. In sql devleper work fine.
Any solution for this problem.

```
Select rpad('Lionel Messi',20,'.') as COL_1 from dual
union all
Select rpad('Cristiano Ronaldo',20,'.') as COL_1 from dual
union all
Select rpad('Pele',20,'.') as COL_1 from dual
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Looks like your Sql developer is using a fixed-pitch font, whereas your DBGrid isn't.  Set your DBGrid to use a fixed-pitch font like `Courier New`i  In any case, it is not very sound practice to use your SQL to do your output formatting for you - it pointlessly consumes server resources for something that should be done by the client..

Comment: @MartynA  Tnx man,Consolas font work fine.  + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your Sql developer is using a fixed-pitch font, whereas your DBGrid isn't. Set your DBGrid to use a fixed-pitch font like Courier New.

In any case, for future reference, it is not very sound practice to use SQL on your SQL Server to do output formatting by using e.g. RPad(), especially when it is applied to every single row of a result set - it pointlessly consumes server resources and network bandwidth for something that should be left to the client to do.